# Duplicate value for resource 'attr/visibility' while upgrading for androidx

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, androidx

I'm trying to migrate androidx and I have an issue which doesn't let me go.

`Android resource compilation failed
Output:  /Users/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2497: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/visibility' with config ''.
/Users/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2497: error: resource previously defined here`

It says that I have an attr named 'visibility' somewhere in my code but I don't have one.

Now should I manipulate the values.xml which the error talks about or not? I think not.

I do have a custom attr.xml which contains the following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
<declare-styleable name="title_separator_settings">
    <attr name="titleText" format="string" localization="suggested" />
    <attr name="valueColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="lineColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="titleSize" format="float" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I hope someone has met with this kind of situation and could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Blind guess - one of your dependencies have this?

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but what can I do with this? I should find which dependency is that I should delete it or download it into the project and modify that?

Comment: I'd start with upgrading my dependencies first. It may be that whatever is causing you problems is already updated for androidx too.

Comment: It was `com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Look out for any library that may have the same attributes.

Comment: It was `com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar` thanks.