# duplicate value for resource 'attr/drawableTintMode'

Tags: android, gradle, facebook-login

Facing this error while building the project.

```
AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/drawableTintMode' with config ''.
```

I Have gone through the solutions of this error which i believe is changing the attr name in `attrs.xml`, but on changing attr name, some of my modules are causing problems.

So is there any other solution.

Please Note - This issue is coming only after i updated facebook Login api from

```
'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.1.0' -> `'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:11.0.0'`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the build log under "Task :app:mergeDebugResources" there might be something like the line `...jetified-facebook-login-11.0.0\res\values\values.xml:12:4: Duplicate value for resource 'attr/drawableTintMode' with config 'DEFAULT' and product ''. Resource was previously defined here: ....\jetified-libraryB-0.0.0.4\res\values\values.xml:6:4: .` 
It seems that Android cannot handle any library's having the same name for any attributes

See example of here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54693933/2373819

And if you look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36936359#comment18

> Basically what I had understood from this thread - if you are
> developing a lib you must take care about your users by prefixing your
> resources(sound good as for me)

If you look at some libraries like:-

https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad/commit/e09688542f11777baa550018cff9c3de2d659252

They have had to rename attributes to get around this problem.

Some like:-

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/res/values/vpi__attrs.xml

Add a prefix that is linked to the library name to prevent attribute clashes.

So probably the facebook library added `drawableTintMode` attribute that is already used by another library you are using.

Probably the only fix is to get one of the clashing libraries to rename the attribute `drawableTintMode` to something more unique by raising a bug against them.